# Slow parsing of fixed-width, alternating-line file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, multiline, fixed-width

I have written a function to parse [this wind file (wind.txt ~1MB)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qn905d7y63siagk/wind.txt?dl=1) into a pandas dataframe but it's pretty slow (according to my colleague) because of the nastiness of the file format. The file linked above is just a subset of the larger file which has hourly wind data from 1900 to 2016. Here's a snippet of the file:

```
2000  1  1 CCB Wdir   5 11 15 14 14 14 14 16 15 15 15 15 13 12 16 16 15 15 15 15 15 14 14 14
2000  1  1 CCB Wspd  10  8  6  8  7  7  8  8  6  8  9  7 16 16  7 10 12 14 15 17 18 22 22 20
2000  1  2 CCB Wdir  14 14 14 14 14 16 16 16 16 15 15 16 17 17 16 17 16 16 16 15 15 15 15 16
2000  1  2 CCB Wspd  17 16 15 17 15 15 16 14 14 15 17 16 15 13 14 15 15 21 20 20 18 25 23 21
2000  1  3 CCB Wdir  15 15 15 16 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 20 18 22 28 27 26 31 32 32 33 33 35 33
2000  1  3 CCB Wspd  20 22 22 18 20 21 21 22 18 16 14 13 15  6  3  7  8  8 13 13 15 10  6  7
```

The columns are *year, month, day, site name, variable name, hour 00, hour 01, hour 02, ... , hour 23.* Wind direction and wind speed appear on alternating lines for each day and the 24 hourly measurements for a single day are all on the same line.

What I'm doing is reading the contents of this file into a single pandas dataframe with a datetime index (hourly frequency) and two columns (wdir and wspd). My parser is below:

```python
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

fil = 'D:\\wind.txt'
lines = open(fil, 'r').readlines()
nl = len(lines)

wdir = lines[0:nl:2]
wspd = lines[1:nl:2]

first = wdir[0].split()
start = pd.datetime(int(first[0]), int(first[1]), int(first[2]), 0)
last = wdir[-1].split()
end = pd.datetime(int(last[0]), int(last[1]), int(last[2]), 23)
drange = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='H')

wind = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.nan, index=drange, columns=['wdir','wspd'])

idate = start

for d in range(nl/2):
    dirStr = wdir[d].split()
    spdStr = wspd[d].split()
    for h in range(24):
        if dirStr[h+5] != '-9' and spdStr[h+5] != '-9':
            wind.wdir[idate] = int(dirStr[h+5]) * 10
            wind.wspd[idate] = int(spdStr[h+5])
        idate += timedelta(hours=1)
        if idate.month == 1 and idate.day == 1 and idate.hour == 1:
            print idate
```

Right now it takes about 2.5 seconds to parse a single year which I think is pretty good, however my colleague thinks that it should be possible to parse the full data file in a few seconds. Is he right? Am I wasting precious time writing slow, clunky parsers?

I work on a massive, legacy FORTRAN77 model and I have a couple dozen similar parsers for various input/output files to be able to analyze/create/modify them in python. If I could be saving time in each of them I would like to know how. Many thanks!

Comment: If your code is already working, you might be better posting this on CodeReview - SO is more for problems in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [pd.read_fwf(...)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) or [pd.read_csv(..., delim_whitespace=True)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) method - it's designed to parse such files...

Demo:

```
cols = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'site', 'var'] + ['{:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(24)]

fn = r'C:\Temp\.data\43763897.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(fn, names=cols, delim_whitespace=True, na_values=['-9'])
x = pd.melt(df,
            id_vars=['year','month','day','site','var'],
            value_vars=df.columns[5:].tolist(),
            var_name='hour')
x['date'] = pd.to_datetime(x[['year','month','day','hour']], errors='coerce')
x = (x.drop(['year','month','day','hour'], 1)
      .pivot_table(index=['date','site'], columns='var', values='value')
      .reset_index())
```

Result:

```
In [12]: x
Out[12]:
var                   date site  Wdir  Wspd
0      2000-01-01 00:00:00  CCB   5.0  10.0
1      2000-01-01 01:00:00  CCB  11.0   8.0
2      2000-01-01 02:00:00  CCB  15.0   6.0
3      2000-01-01 03:00:00  CCB  14.0   8.0
4      2000-01-01 04:00:00  CCB  14.0   7.0
5      2000-01-01 05:00:00  CCB  14.0   7.0
6      2000-01-01 06:00:00  CCB  14.0   8.0
7      2000-01-01 07:00:00  CCB  16.0   8.0
8      2000-01-01 08:00:00  CCB  15.0   6.0
9      2000-01-01 09:00:00  CCB  15.0   8.0
...                    ...  ...   ...   ...
149030 2016-12-31 14:00:00  CCB   0.0   0.0
149031 2016-12-31 15:00:00  CCB   1.0   5.0
149032 2016-12-31 16:00:00  CCB  33.0   8.0
149033 2016-12-31 17:00:00  CCB  34.0   9.0
149034 2016-12-31 18:00:00  CCB  35.0   7.0
149035 2016-12-31 19:00:00  CCB   0.0   0.0
149036 2016-12-31 20:00:00  CCB  12.0   8.0
149037 2016-12-31 21:00:00  CCB  13.0   7.0
149038 2016-12-31 22:00:00  CCB  15.0   7.0
149039 2016-12-31 23:00:00  CCB  17.0   7.0

[149040 rows x 4 columns]
```

Timing with your `wind.txt` file:

```
In [10]: %%timeit
    ...: cols = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'site', 'var'] + ['{:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(24)]
    ...: fn = r'D:\download\wind.txt'
    ...: df = pd.read_csv(fn, names=cols, delim_whitespace=True, na_values=['-9'])
    ...: x = pd.melt(df,
    ...:             id_vars=['year','month','day','site','var'],
    ...:             value_vars=df.columns[5:].tolist(),
    ...:             var_name='hour')
    ...: x['date'] = pd.to_datetime(x[['year','month','day','hour']], errors='coerce')
    ...: x = (x.drop(['year','month','day','hour'], 1)
    ...:       .pivot_table(index=['date','site'], columns='var', values='value')
    ...:       .reset_index())
    ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 812 ms per loop
```

Comment: I have tried using pd.read_fwf() for this and other applications. The problems I've faced are (1) the alternating direction/speed rows is really hard to work around (2) busting out each of the hourly measurement columns into their own uniquely indexed row is difficult and (3) because there is no actual hour field, automatically parsing dates is nearly impossible. While it is possible to get pd.read_fwf() to work with this input file, it's considerably slower and much more complicated than the process described above....unless I'm doing something wrong, which is definitely a possibility.

Comment: @Taylor, do you need a `site name` column in the resulting DF?

Comment: Using MaxU's code and with your wind.txt, I get a 3.5s for 298080 rows.  Just had to add errors='coerce' to the pd.to_datetime.

Comment: @ScottBoston, thank you for the timing! I have also added `errors='coerce'   to the pd.to_datetime`

Comment: I was working on an answer myself, you beat me to it. :)  I had to test it.

Comment: @ScottBoston, on my notebook it takes 22s for 600.000 rows. I'm pretty sure we can do it bit faster. I think it would be pretty helpful to have different answers - please post your answer

Comment: @MaxU... Yeah, I am using windows and have a few other things running.  Still, the answer the OP is, yes, his co-worker is right.  You should be able to process that entire file in seconds.

Comment: This is absolutely gorgeous! I have never even seen the *pd.melt()* function before and never thought about using the original as an already pivoted table. Bravo. One very small thing...when it gets to a double-digit month it's only picking up the second digit (eg 10 read in as 0, 11 as 1, 12 as 2). I assume this is because column widths are inferred based on first *n* columns but I'm not sure what n is or how to fix it...

Comment: I actually fixed my problem by using `pd.read_csv(fn, sep='\s*', engine='python', names=cols, na_values='-9')` and it reads the entire file in a matter of seconds. I am blown away by how brilliant this community is! Currently going back and editing as many of my functions as possible. There may be more questions coming soon. Thanks a million!

Comment: I think `sep='\s*', engine='python'` is the same thing as using `delim_whitespace=True`. You'll have to test to see if that's faster, but since it stays with the C engine, I'd think it would be.